# Expanding this Regular Expressions to remove all special characters

Tags: c#, regex

How can I expand this to remove any special characters e.g. `:` `;` `,` etc. but still do what it does now which is remove `<div>` tags:

```
string BBCSplit = Regex.Replace(BBC, @"<(.|\n)*?>", string.Empty);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "special"? Is anything except a letter or a number "special"? Is there anything else you want to keep?

Comment: its ok, but why don't you take the trouble to learn regular expressions. ITs not like there's hundreds of tutorials on the web. Then you wouldn't have to ask roughly the same question over and over again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string BBCSplit = Regex.Replace(BBC, @"<(.|\n)*?>|[:;]", string.Empty);
```

By careful if the "special" characters you want to remove include '"", ']', etc.--you'll need to put a '\' before them.

Comment: This looks right, I would add "\," to it based on the examples. and also I was wondering, should the characters inside the []s be separated by a comma(or perhaps even a pipe)?? so something like [:,\,,;]

Comment: @gnomed -- No, the characters in the square brackets should not be separated by anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can add more with the alternation character (pipe or |).

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways to do it in RegEx, Markus's answer to remove quotes, brackets, newlines, and punctuation would be:  (remember to double your doublequote within an @ string)

```
@"<(.|\n)*?>|[:;,!@#$%^&*()-_+='""[\]]"
```

Another method would be to remove any non-space and non-alphanumeric character.

```
@"<(.|\n)*?>|[^\s\w]"
```

I would suggest being more strict with your RegEx.  If you want to remove just tags, go with:

```
@"</?\w*(.|\s)*?>|[^ \w]"
```